# How to install urbanaccess git repository in windows using Anaconda Prompt?

Tags: python-2.7, github, anaconda

I'm trying to install it but I'm a beginner so I don't know what I should type in conda to clone the git repository and run it.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Follow the instructions here, https://github.com/UDST/urbanaccess#installation. If Anaconda is installed then any "python" command defaults to the python installed by Anaconda. To use git first install it.

```
conda install git
```

Then the instructions state:

```
git clone https://github.com/UDST/urbanaccess.git
```

Move into this directory and install:

```
cd urbanaccess
python setup.py develop
```